# Configure Dns Zone in Azure to receive email in gsuite?

Tags: azure, dns, google-workspace, custom-domain

I've configured my domain in my domain registrar to point to my azure dns zone, and I want to be able to receive emails in gsuite with my domain? Everything I've read tells me that I have to configure a MX record in my azure dns but I'm having trouble to match the data gsuite is telling me to add to the mx record.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have [hosted your domain in Azure DNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-delegate-domain-azure-dns). That means that you have used the Azure provided name servers in your domain provider. Thus, you can managed DNS records in Azure DNS zone.

Refer to the *Step 4: Add the G Suite MX records* in [this document](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7174013?hl=en). To direct your email to your G Suite account, you have to add new MX records to your domain and remove old MX records if there is. Then tell Google to find your new MX records in Step 5.

These are the records that you need to add in your Azure DNS zone for your domain:

```
MX server address                Priority
ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM               1
ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM          5
ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM          5
ALT3.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM          10
ALT4.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM          10
```

If you don't know how to add MX records in Azure DNS, you can refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/dns/create-dns-records-for-azure-dns-zones?view=o365-worldwide#add-an-mx-record-so-email-for-your-domain-will-come-to-microsoft). This may take 24-48 hours for DNS propagation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes as Nancy Xiong already replied, seems to be working, interestingly but initially I found this article:
https://support.google.com/domains/answer/9428703?hl=en
Which gives different mx entries and it didn't work, waited for several hours, usually it should be within several minutes since the domain is already pointed to your custom name servers, but then adding it as suggested here https://support.google.com/a/answer/33915?hl=en#zippy=%2Cstep-add-new-mx-records
did the trick
So at the end of the day I've ended up with this list:
[image]

And its working now.